# Magento 2 - frontend notices and login do not work

Tags: magento2, customer-session

I just installed Magento 2.1.5. I can login on the admin side and everything appears to work as expect there. However, I cannot login on the customer side and no notifications appear during the login process.

- I can see in the cookies that messages are being set (invalid password, etc..)
- When I dump the values provided in the form key validator I see that Magento's form keys are not matching
- My site is accessible at m2.domain.com. My cookie domain is set to m2.domain.com.

Comment: For a little more information, when you say you installed 2.1.5, where did you do this? did you install this on a remote server or locally? Magento doesn't play nice with things like 'localhost' on a mamp install, so that might make the difference on tracking down what is happening.

Comment: Sorry, I thought my last bullet point made this clear. I have it installed on a remote server whose endpoint is m2.domain.com. Hope this helps.

Comment: no, that's my mistake, didn't read that right.

Comment: Having the exact problem, with correct directory permissions, since backend login is working so i believe permissions are not the problem, has to do something to do with the form key, some how the form key from the frontend form and the session's form key are not the same when compared

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's the **folder permissions**, but run these commands:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage cache:clean &
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy || mage setup:static-content:deploy -f;
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: why run setup:static-content:deploy twice?

Answer (score 0):

We entered nothing in the Cookie-Domain field. Just let it empty.